# Compile errors in zlib opencv 2.4.5 mac osx

Tags: macos, opencv, osx-mountain-lion, zlib, xcode4.6

I am trying to compile OpenCV 2.4.5 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion.
I've made project with the command "cmake -G Xcode" so I can build it within Xcode.
I've changed C++ Language Dialect to compiler-default and C++ Standard Library to libc++.

The setting Header Search Paths is set to '`/opt/local/include/`**'.
These settings should be sufficient to build OpenCV, but I get the following error in the zlib library:

Semantic Issue Group

```
Warning: /opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c:216:20: Passing 'const Bytef *' (aka 'const unsigned char *') to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers
```

`Error: /opencv/3rdparty/zlib/gzwrite.c:273:41:` Read-only variable is not assignable

The error occurs on `line 273 in gzwrite.c: strm->next_in[strm->avail_in++] = c;`

```
/* try writing to input buffer for speed (state->size == 0 if buffer not
   initialized) */
if (strm->avail_in < state->size) {
    if (strm->avail_in == 0)
        strm->next_in = state->in;
    strm->next_in[strm->avail_in++] = c;
    state->x.pos++;
    return c & 0xff;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing so I can solve the error?

Comment: Do you mean the version I installed or the one that is included in OpenCV?

Comment: The version you are trying to compile that is giving you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/madler/zlib/commit/62d6112a7981ad7c34f3b43cffdf00d4662a4f25) in [zlib 1.2.8](http://zlib.net/).

Comment: So the only thing that I have to do is replace zlib in the OpenCV project with the most recent version?

Comment: I replaced zlib in the OpenCV project and the project compiled. Thank you for your help.